# adding child nodes in treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

I'm new to C# and don't have any programming experience. But I've finish a C# basics.
Now I would like to design a simple tree view by adding parent node and child node.

I would like to add a second child for the Second node, I'm quite stuck here and don't know what's next.

Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
    private void addParentNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string yourParentNode;
        yourParentNode = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        treeView2.Nodes.Add(yourParentNode);
    }

    private void addChildNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string yourChildNode;
        yourChildNode = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        treeView2.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(yourChildNode);
    }
```

Sorry I wasn't clear, I'm not sure if I really need this one here:

```
  //treeView1.BeginUpdate(); 
  //treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
```

What I'm trying to do, is to add Parent Nodes and child node. In my code, I can add several Parent Nodes, but if I want to add a child node, it only add in the first parent node. 
I want that if I add a child node, I want to add it to the second parent or third parent.

In my code I only use one treeview here which names as treeview2
Here is the [**screenshot**](http://www.mypicx.com/05192009/error/)

this is how my final code looks like:
Before I put the else, I'm getting an error if I don't select anything. So I made it that way that if there is nothing selected it will add the "child node" to the "default node" or (parent1 node). It seems to work good. Thanks guys;-)

```
    //This is for adding a parent node
    private void addParentNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeView2.BeginUpdate();

        string yourParentNode;
        yourParentNode = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        treeView2.Nodes.Add(yourParentNode);
        treeView2.EndUpdate();
    }

    //This is for adding child node
    private void addChildNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeView2.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            string yourChildNode;
            yourChildNode = textBox1.Text.Trim();

            treeView2.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(yourChildNode);
            treeView2.ExpandAll();
        }
        //This is for adding the child node to the default node(parent 1 node)
        else
        {
            string yourChildNode;
            yourChildNode = textBox1.Text.Trim();
            treeView2.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(yourChildNode);
        }
```

Additional question: Are there any other ways on how the code be better? Because here, I declare the string "yourChildNode" twice. One in the if and other one in the else, are there any simplification?

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what you are trying to do here. You seem to have 2 tree view controls, but only one of them is in use. What is the relevance of the first one in your code sample? At what point in the heirarchy of the tree view do you want to add nodes? Perhaps a screenshot or mockup of the effect might help here

Comment: ---Your Solution is Here---

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861371/adding-nodes-to-a-specific-parent-node-in-a-treeview-c

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not that bad, but you forgot to call `treeView2.EndUpdate()` in your `addParentNode_Click()` method.
You can also call `treeView2.ExpandAll()` at the end of your `addChildNode_Click()` method to see your child node directly.

```
private void addParentNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  treeView2.BeginUpdate();
  //treeView2.Nodes.Clear();
  string yourParentNode;
  yourParentNode = textBox1.Text.Trim();
  treeView2.Nodes.Add(yourParentNode);
  treeView2.EndUpdate();
}

private void addChildNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (treeView2.SelectedNode != null) {
    string yourChildNode;
    yourChildNode = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    treeView2.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(yourChildNode);
    treeView2.ExpandAll();
  }
}
```

I don't know if it was a mistake or not but there was 2 TreeViews. I changed it to only 1 TreeView...

EDIT: Answer to the additional question:
You can declare the variable holding the child node name outside of the if clause:

```
private void addChildNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var childNode = textBox1.Text.Trim();
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childNode)) {
    TreeNode parentNode = treeView2.SelectedNode ?? treeView2.Nodes[0];
    if (parentNode != null) {
      parentNode.Nodes.Add(childNode);
      treeView2.ExpandAll();
    }
  }
}
```

Note: see http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/csharp2/nullable.html for info about the ?? operator.

Comment: thanks Julien, your code works but I would like to add the child node2 in the second parent node. 
With this code, if I add the childnode2 to the parentnode2 it doesn't do that way. It always add the new child to the parentnode1.

Comment: Do you want to add a child node to the last inserted node or to the selected node?

Comment: to the selected node for example.

Comment: There you go, I edited my answer. Hope I did it correctly this time ;)

Comment: hey Julien Thanks a lot that's what I need;-) you're an angel;-)

Comment: When you do this for real :) make sure you check SelectedNode is not null before you try to use it!

Answer (score 14):

May i add to Stormenet example some KISS (Keep It Simple & Stupid):

If you already have a treeView or just created an instance of it:
Let's populate with some data - Ex. One parent two child's :

```
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("ParentKey","Parent Text");
            treeView1.Nodes["ParentKey"].Nodes.Add("Child-1 Text");
            treeView1.Nodes["ParentKey"].Nodes.Add("Child-2 Text");
```

Another Ex. two parent's first have two child's second one child:

```
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("ParentKey1","Parent-1  Text");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("ParentKey2","Parent-2 Text");
            treeView1.Nodes["ParentKey1"].Nodes.Add("Child-1 Text");
            treeView1.Nodes["ParentKey1"].Nodes.Add("Child-2 Text");
            treeView1.Nodes["ParentKey2"].Nodes.Add("Child-3 Text");
```

Take if farther - sub child of child 2:

```
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("ParentKey1","Parent-1  Text");
            treeView1.Nodes["ParentKey1"].Nodes.Add("Child-1 Text");
            treeView1.Nodes["ParentKey1"].Nodes.Add("ChildKey2","Child-2 Text");
            treeView1.Nodes["ParentKey1"].Nodes["ChildKey2"].Nodes.Add("Child-3 Text");
```

As you see you can have as many child's and parent's as you want and those can have sub child's of child's and so on....
Hope i help!

Answer (score 5):

Example of adding child nodes:

```
private void AddExampleNodes()
        {
            TreeNode node;

            node = treeView1.Nodes.Add("Master node");
            node.Nodes.Add("Child node");
            node.Nodes.Add("Child node 2");

            node = treeView1.Nodes.Add("Master node 2");
            node.Nodes.Add("mychild");
            node.Nodes.Add("mychild");
        }
```

Comment: Hi Stormenet, thanks. But I think this one is a finished treeview, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are only adding children to the first parent `treeView2.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(yourChildNode)`
Depending on how you want it to behave, you need to be explicit about the parent node you wish to add the child to.
For Example, from your screenshot, if you wanted to add the child to the second node you would need:
`treeView2.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(yourChildNode)`
If you want to add the children to the currently selected node, get the `TreeView.SelectedNode` and add the children to it.

Try [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(VS.80).aspx) to get an idea of how the class operates.  Unfortunately the msdn documentation is pretty light on the code samples...
I'm missing a whole lot of safety checks here!
Something like (untested):

```
private void addChildNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TreeNode ParentNode = treeView2.SelectedNode;  // for ease of debugging!
  if (ParentNode != null) {
    ParentNode.Nodes.Add("Name Of Node");
    treeView2.ExpandAll();   // so you can see what's been added              
    treeView2.Invalidate();  // requests a redraw
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Byron, I would like to add the child node to the selected parent node. 
You mentioned, the TreeView.SelectedNode 
where can I add it? in the addParentNode or add_ChildNode button?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Byron, in your code "Treenode" is it "TreeNode" or "Treenode". Because if I type "Treenode" I got a red mark. Which means something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar and came across the same issues. I used the AfterSelect event to make sure I wasn't getting the previously selected node.

It's actually really easy to reference the correct node to receive the new child node.

```
private void TreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
   //show dialogbox to let user name the new node
   frmDialogInput f = new frmDialogInput();
   f.ShowDialog();

    //find the node that was selected
    TreeNode myNode = TreeView1.SelectedNode;
    //create the new node to add
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(f.EnteredText);
    //add the new child to the selected node
    myNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Guys use this code for adding nodes and childnodes for TreeView from C# code.**
*

KISS (Keep It Simple & Stupid :)*

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
        TreeNode a1 = new TreeNode("Apple");

        TreeNode b1 = new TreeNode("Banana");
        TreeNode a2 = new TreeNode("gree apple");
        TreeView2.Nodes.Add(a1);
        TreeView2.Nodes.Add(b1);
        a1.ChildNodes.Add(a2);
```

}

Comment: There's no '&' in KISS

Comment: It's Nodes. There's no ChildNotes property.

Answer (score 0):

```
void treeView(string [] LineString)
    {
        int line = LineString.Length;
        string AssmMark = "";
        string PartMark = "";
        TreeNode aNode;
        TreeNode pNode;
        for ( int i=0 ; i<line ; i++){
            string sLine = LineString[i];
            if ( sLine.StartsWith("ASSEMBLY:") ){
                sLine  = sLine.Replace("ASSEMBLY:","");
                string[] aData = sLine.Split(new char[] {','});
                AssmMark  = aData[0].Trim();
                //TreeNode aNode;
                //aNode = new TreeNode(AssmMark);
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(AssmMark,AssmMark);
            }
            if( sLine.Trim().StartsWith("PART:") ){
                sLine  = sLine.Replace("PART:","");
                string[] pData = sLine.Split(new char[] {','});
                PartMark = pData[0].Trim();
                pNode = new TreeNode(PartMark);
                treeView1.Nodes[AssmMark].Nodes.Add(pNode);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows to Populate treeView with parent and child node. And also with display and value member of  parent and child nodes:

```
   arrayRoot = taskData.GetRocordForRoot();  // iterate through database table
    for (int j = 0; j <arrayRoot.length; j++) { 
                TreeNode root = new TreeNode();  // Creating new root node
                root.Text = "displayString";
                root.Tag = "valueString";
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(root); //Adding the root node

             arrayChild = taskData.GetRocordForChild();// iterate through database table
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayChild.length; i++) {
                    TreeNode child = new TreeNode(); // creating child node
                    child.Text = "displayString"
                    child.Tag = "valueString";
                    root.Nodes.Add(child); // adding child node
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NIKOLAY;Initial Catalog=PlanZadanie;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public void loadTree(TreeView tree)
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [RAZDEL_ID],[NAME_RAZDEL] FROM [tbl_RAZDEL]";
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    tree.Nodes.Add(reader.GetString(1));
                    tree.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("yourChildNode");
                    tree.ExpandAll();

                }

                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка с сообщением: " + ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Comment: When answering questions it is best to explain in more detail so that it can be more easily understood by other users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve that code

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
         D:\root\Project1\A\A.pdf
         D:\root\Project1\B\t.pdf
         D:\root\Project2\c.pdf
         */
        List<string> n = new List<string>();
        List<string> kn = new List<string>();
        n = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\root\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        kn = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\root\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
        foreach (var item in kn)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < treeView1.Nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            n = Directory.GetFiles(treeView1.Nodes[i].Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
            for (int zik = 0; zik < n.Count; zik++)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(n[zik].ToString());
            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void tree()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();


    var node = db.ChartOfAccounts.
    Include(c => c.chartOfAccounts)
    .Where(c => c.parent_account == null).ToList();

    foreach (var account in node)
    {
               treeView1.Nodes.Add(account.account_title);

                 var node1 = db.ChartOfAccounts
                .Where(c => c.parent_account == account.c_id).ToList();
                 bool t1 = db.ChartOfAccounts.Any(c => c.parent_account == account.c_id);
                 if (!t1) { counter = counter + 1; }
                else
                 {
                    foreach (var item in node1)
                     { treeView1.Nodes[(counter)].Nodes.Add(item.account_title);

                          bool test1 = db.ChartOfAccounts
                          .Any(c => c.parent_account == item.c_id);
                          if (!test1) { counter1 = counter1 + 1; }
                          else { 
                                      var node2 = db.ChartOfAccounts
                                  .Where(c => c.parent_account == item.c_id).ToList();

                                    foreach (var item2 in node2)
                                    {
                                        treeView1.Nodes[counter].Nodes[(counter1)].Nodes.Add(item2.account_title);

                                        bool test2 = db.ChartOfAccounts
                                        .Any(c => c.parent_account == item2.c_id);
                                        if (!test2) { counter2 = counter2 + 1; }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            var node3 = db.ChartOfAccounts
                                        .Where(c => c.parent_account == item2.c_id).ToList();

                                            foreach (var item3 in node3)
                                            { treeView1.Nodes[counter].Nodes[counter1].Nodes[counter2].Nodes.Add(item3.account_title); }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                     }
                    counter = counter + 1;
                 }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are **10 existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with over **twenty votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Comment: Please at least fix your indentation and coding style. I have added more helpful markdown for you and unindented everything by a couple of levels, but the rest is up to you.