# How to add to a TreeView directory at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a `TreeView` in which I would like to allow the user to add and delete subitems from. In exploring basic functionality I am using a `button` and a `textbox` to add this subitem. When the user clicks on the `button` a new `TreeViewItem` needs to be created and set as a subitem of my parent `TreeView` with the `text` from the `textbox` set as the subitem's `Header`.

This is my current code under the `button_click` event:

```
//ADD T_ITEM TO PARENT TREEVIEW
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
       item.Header = textBox1.Text;

       //Compiler does not recognize "Nodes"
       Parent.Nodes.Add(item);
}
```

Specifically, the compiler has a problem with `Nodes`. The main [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881607/adding-child-nodes-in-treeview) that I've used to help me makes a lot of sense, but just doesn't work for me. All of the sources I have looked at uses the `Nodes` command at one time or another with no problem. Do I need to include a reference, or is my code completely off?

--[This](http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview) guide uses `System.Windows.Forms;` in order to use `Nodes`, but doesn't seem to help because I am using Windows Presentation Foundation.

Please show me how to get my code working in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Your other question's accepted answer is for winforms and has nothing to do with WPF. Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. Use a proper ViewModel instead.

Comment: Can you show me an example in maybe an answer? (And it was someone else's question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research and found the equivalent method for adding child `TreeViewItems` to parent `TreeViewItems` in WPF.

This is the change I made to my code:

```
//ADD T_ITEM TO PARENT TREEVIEW
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
      item.Header = textBox1.Text;

      Parent.Items.Add(item);
}
```