# How to rename headers of dynamically created TreeView Items

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm new to the `TreeView` in WPF: C#, and I am learning how to work with dynamically created `TreeViewItems`. Right now, my program allows the user to create dynamic `TreeViewItems` and then delete them. For my next step I would like to program the ability to rename these dynamic items. Theoretically, this process is pretty self explanatory, however, I do not know what to do with the C# code.

First of all, I would like to outline my renaming process, to show exactly where I need help.

1. User right-clicks on the `TreeViewItem`
2. A `contextMenu` drops down (DONE)
3. User clicks on "Rename..." and a window opens up (DONE)
4. Name of `TreeViewItem` is entered into `textBox` (DONE)
5. If the text in the `textBox` matches a `header` in the mainWindow's `TreeView`, another window opens up that allows the user to enter the new name for the `TreeViewItem`. (INCOMPLETE)
6. When the name is entered in the new window, the user clicks enter and the name of the item is changed to whatever was entered in the `textBox`. (INCOMPLETE)

Here is my code for step 5, where the program needs to verify that the `header` entered exists in the `TreeView`. In the areas where I am unsure about the correct code, I have pseudo code.

```
//ENTER - Select TreeViewItem, open enterName window
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       //Query for Window1
       var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows
           .Cast<Window1>()
           .FirstOrDefault(window => window is Window1) as Window1;

       //If(textbox1.text == one of the treeViewItem headers)
       var newWindow = new EnterCartName();
       newWindow.Show();

       //else,
       //MessageBox.Show("Value entered does not match a current cart name");
       //this.Close();
}
```

For step 6, I understand how to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866294/how-to-add-to-a-treeview-directory-at-runtime) a `TreeViewItem` with a dynamically created `header`, but I am unsure how to get and rename an existing one. This is my code:

```
//ENTER - Change cart name
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       this.Close(); //close Window

       //Query for Window1
       var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows
           .Cast<Window1>()
           .FirstOrDefault(window => window is Window1) as Window1;

       //mainWindow.treeViewItem.Header(TVI gotten from previous window) = textBox1.Text;
}
```

I think my main problem with dynamic `TreeView` assets is that I feel like they are invisible to me. How am I supposed to do work with them if I don't know what they're called, or how to properly reference them. If you know of any guides or resources on this topic please feel free to share.

Thanks a lot.

**My Final Solution:**

```
//Now Global
bool hasFoundMatch;

//ENTER - Select cart, open enter name window
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       string input, output;

       //Query for Window1
       var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows
           .Cast<Window1>()
           .FirstOrDefault(window => window is Window1) as Window1;

       //Get TreeViewItem from mainWindow
       TreeViewItem renameCart = mainWindow.cartTypes_TI;
       input = textBox1.Text;
       output = textBox2.Text;

       //Check if header exists
       hasFoundMatch = CheckItemHeader(renameCart.Items, input);

       //if header exists - set new header
       //Else - show message box
       if (hasFoundMatch == true)
           SetItemHeader(renameCart.Items, input, output);
       else
           MessageBox.Show("Value entered does not match a current cart name.");

       //close window
       this.Close();
}

//Checks to see whether the user entered header exists
private bool CheckItemHeader(ItemCollection treeViewItems, string input)
{
       bool hasFoundMatch = false;
       for (int index = 0; index < treeViewItems.Count; index++)
       {
           TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)treeViewItems[index];
           string header = item.Header.ToString();

           if(header == input)
           {
                 hasFoundMatch = true;
                 break;
           }
           else
                 hasFoundMatch = false;
       }
       return hasFoundMatch;
}

//Changes the selected TVI header
private void SetItemHeader(ItemCollection treeViewItems, string input, string output)
{
       for (int index = 0; index < treeViewItems.Count; index++)
       {
           TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)treeViewItems[index];
           string header = item.Header.ToString();
           if (header == input)
           {
               item.Header = output;
               break;
           }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well setting the header is as easy as:

```
treeViewItem.Header = textBox1.Text;
```

Finding it should be similar to finding whether any `TreeViewItem.Header` matches the text provided in the `TextBox`:

```
private void SetItemHeader(ItemCollection treeViewItems, string input, string output)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < treeViewItems.Count; index++)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)treeViewItems[index];
        if (item.Header == input)
        {
            item.Header = output;
            return;
        }
        else if (item.Items.Count > 1) SetItemHeader(item.Items, input, output);
    }
}
```

UPDATE >>>

You could use this method to check the item headers... if it returns true, you have a match:

```
private bool CheckItemHeader(ItemCollection treeViewItems, string input)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < treeViewItems.Count; index++)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)treeViewItems[index];
        if (item.Header == input) return true;
        else if (item.Items.Count > 1) return CheckItemHeader(item.Items, input);
    }
    return false;
}
```

You would use it like:

```
bool hasFoundMatch = CheckItemHeader(treeView.Items, textInputToMatch);
```

Then when you have the value to change the header to:

```
SetItemHeader(treeView.Items, textInputToMatch, textToChangeHeaderTo);
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, but this way doesn't incorporate step 6, or my second window. Are you suggesting the user enters in both the name of the `TreeViewItem` and the new name of it in the same window?

Comment: No, I thought that you might be able to edit this method very slightly yourself for your header matching method and then use this one for your header updating. However, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Alright, I just updated my answer with your solution. The check keeps returning as false though (and I am definitely entering the correct name).

Comment: You're supposed to pass the `ItemCollection` from the `TreeView` into the `CheckItemHeader` method, not just one `TreeViewItem`... unless all of the other `TreeViewItem`s are its children. You're going to have to debug those methods to see what items are being passed in... you're the only one that *can* do that.

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the `TreeViewItem` because I only want to deal with its children. So in that case I should debug?