# How to sort a treeview that has stackpanel items

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, treeview

i tried to create somthing to quickly locate and watch files. So i created a TreeView that has StackPanels as Items. A StackPanel contains an Image an a Label.

```
    private TreeViewItem createFile(string Name, string soureFile)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem();
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        Image i = new Image();
        Label l_Text = new Label();
        Label l_FileName = new Label();

        l_FileName.Content = soureFile;
        l_FileName.Width = 0;
        l_Text.Content = Name;

        System.Drawing.Bitmap dImg = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Picture");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        dImg.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();
        bImg.BeginInit();
        bImg.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
        bImg.EndInit();
        i.Source = bImg;
        i.Height = 20;
        i.Width = 20;

        sp.Name = "SP_File";
        sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        sp.Children.Add(i);
        sp.Children.Add(l_Text);
        sp.Children.Add(l_FileName);
        tvi.Header = sp;

        return tvi;
    }
```

One can create logical folders (just for creating a structure) and add files and other folders to the folders (just references to to the actual file on the hdd). This worked fine until i tried to sort the TreeView. I read stuff on on Sorting TreeViews with

```
    SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Header", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Obviously this doesn't work for me since i cant exchange "Header" with "Header.StackPanel.Label.Text"
As I read a little bit further it seems I used the wrong approach to the whole thing by not using MVVM ([Numerically sort a List of TreeViewItems in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949777/numerically-sort-a-list-of-treeviewitems-in-c-sharp)).

Since I have litte to no experience with MVVM can someone explain to me how it is best do this with MVVM? I use a List of "watchedFile" to keep the files and folders.

I basically have the the following class for a file

```
class watchedFile
{
    public string name { get; private set; }
    public string path { get; private set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; private set; }

    public watchedFile(string Name, string Path, List<string> Tags)
    {
        name = Name;
        path = Path;
        tags = Tags;
    }        
}
```

If path is null or empty its a folder. The TreeViewItem has a little Image which shows a little "folder" or "picture", a label which shows the "watchedFile.name" and an invisible label which contains the watchedfile.path (which is only shown as a tooltip). I guess I should do this with DataBinding so I dont need to add an invisible Label.

Questions:

1. How can I solve the task using MVVM?
2. How/where can I bind the Image to the TreeViewItem when I have just the wacthedFile.path to distinguish?
3. How do I sort the watched items?
4. How do I keep track of the TreeView level (so i can rebuild the structure from a saved file)?
5. Is there a way to sort a TreeView with StackPanel Items without using MVVM/Data-Binding?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do this MVVM fashion.

First, write viewmodel classes. Here, we've got a main viewmodel that has a collection of `WatchedFile` instances, and then we've got the `WatchedFile` class itself. I've also decided to make `Tag` a class, instead of just using strings. This lets us write data templates in the XAML that explicitly and exclusively will be used to display `Tag` instances, rather than strings in general. The UI is full of strings.

The notification properties are tedious to write if you don't have a snippet. [I have snippets](https://swissarmycrowbar.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/viewmodel-property-snippets-c6/) (Steal them! They're not nailed down!).

Once you've got this, sorting is no big deal. If you want to sort the root level items, those are `WatchedFile`.

```
SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

But we'll do that in XAML below.

Serialization is simple, too: Just make your viewmodel classes serializable. The important thing here is that your sorting and serialization don't have to care what's in the treeview item templates. StackPanels, GroupBoxes, whatever -- it doesn't matter at all, because your sorting and serialization code just deals with your data classes, not the UI stuff. You can change the visual details in the data templates radically without having to worry about it affecting any other part of the code. That's what's nice about MVVM.

Viewmodels:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WatchedFile.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class WatchedFile : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Name Property
        private String _name = default(String);
        public String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _name)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion Name Property

        #region Path Property
        private String _path = default(String);
        public String Path
        {
            get { return _path; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _path)
                {
                    _path = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion Path Property

        #region Tags Property
        private ObservableCollection<Tag> _tags = new ObservableCollection<Tag>();
        public ObservableCollection<Tag> Tags
        {
            get { return _tags; }
            protected set
            {
                if (value != _tags)
                {
                    _tags = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion Tags Property
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public Tag(String value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
        public String Value { get; private set; }
    }

    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Populate();
        }

        public void Populate()
        {
            //  Arbitrary test info, just for display. 
            WatchedFiles = new ObservableCollection<WatchedFile>
            {
                new WatchedFile() { Name = "foobar.txt", Path = "c:\\testfiles\\foobar.txt", Tags = { new Tag("Testfile"), new Tag("Text") } },
                new WatchedFile() { Name = "bazfoo.txt", Path = "c:\\testfiles\\bazfoo.txt", Tags = { new Tag("Testfile"), new Tag("Text") } },
                new WatchedFile() { Name = "whatever.xml", Path = "c:\\testfiles\\whatever.xml", Tags = { new Tag("Testfile"), new Tag("XML") } },
            };
        }

        #region WatchedFiles Property
        private ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> _watchedFiles = new ObservableCollection<WatchedFile>();
        public ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> WatchedFiles
        {
            get { return _watchedFiles; }
            protected set
            {
                if (value != _watchedFiles)
                {
                    _watchedFiles = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion WatchedFiles Property
    }
}
```

Code behind. Note I only added one line here to what the wizard gave me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WatchedFile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new ViewModels.MainViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly the XAML:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="WatchedFile.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WatchedFile"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WatchedFile.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource 
                x:Key="SortedWatchedFiles" 
                Source="{Binding WatchedFiles}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" Direction="Ascending" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedWatchedFiles}}"
            >
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                    DataType="{x:Type vm:WatchedFile}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}"
                    >
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="{Binding Name}" 
                        ToolTip="{Binding Path}"
                        />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                    DataType="{x:Type vm:Tag}"
                    >
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="{Binding Value}" 
                        />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The XAML is less than obvious. `TreeView.Resources` is in scope for any child of the `TreeView`. The `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s don't have an `x:Key` property, which makes them *implicit*. That means that when the `TreeView`'s items are instantiated, each of the root items will have a `WatchedFile` class instance for its `DataContext`. Since `WatchedFile` has an implicit data template, that  will be used to fill in its content. `TreeView` is recursive, so it uses `HierarchicalDataTemplate` instead of regular `DataTemplate`. `HierarchicalDataTemplate` adds the `ItemSource` property, which tells the item where to look for its children on its `DataContext` object. `WatchedFile.Tags` is the `ItemsSource` for the root-level tree items. Those are `Tag`, which has its own implicit `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. It doesn't have children so it doesn't use `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource`.

Since all our collections are `ObservableCollection<T>`, you can add and remove items from any collection at any time and the UI will update automagically. You can do the same with the `Name` and `Path` properties of `WatchedFile`, because it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and its properties raise `PropertyChanged` when their values change. The XAML UI subscribes to all the notification events without being told, and does the right thing -- assuming you've told it what it needs to know to do that.

Your codebehind can grab `SortedWatchedFiles` with `FindResource` and change its `SortDescriptions`, but this makes more sense to me, since it's agnostic about how you're populating the treeview:

```
    <Button Content="Re-Sort" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

    <!-- ... snip ... -->

    <TreeView
        x:Name="WatchedFilesTreeView"
        ...etc. as before...
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(WatchedFilesTreeView.ItemsSource);

    cv.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    cv.SortDescriptions.Add(
        new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Name", 
            System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your very detailed answer - i like it very much. it works fine so far and it hink i got a bit more into MVVM. howeever I still got some problems. I would like a file/folder to have have multiple entries of itself. so i added an observable collection to the WatchedFile

Comment: please see the next "answer" for further questions

Comment: sorry I failed to read correctly ;) replaced `ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}"` with `ItemsSource="{Binding Subs}"`

Comment: What do i have to add so that the sub items of the TreeView (now WatchedFiles, too) are beeing sorted as well as the root items?

Comment: @Thoms The quickest way is to have `WatchedFile` sort the collection itself. A more respectable MVVM approach is to use a value converter to convert the collection to a sorted CollectionViewSource; [here are two variations on that theme](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5730402/424129). The multi-value-converter answer (scroll down a bit) is really slick, because you can bind to properties to control how they're sorted at runtime. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: I tried to do it within `WatchedFile` and `WatchedFiles`. The problem is it works wenn i create a new instance of say `WatchedFiles` but when i Add an instance of `WatchedFile` to `WatchedFiles` with `WatchedFiles.Add(instance)` it doesn't do anything. I did the sorting in the set accessor. But it isn't called when using Add(...)

Comment: Ok I think i finally did it... I used the  `CollectionChanged` event and then did the sorting in the handler: `public ObservableCollection<WatchedFile> Subs
        {
            get { return _subs; }
            protected set
            {
                if (value != _subs)
                {
                    _subs = value;
                    _subs.CollectionChanged += _subs_CollectionChanged;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: @Thoms Ah, OK, now I get where you're coming from. `Add()` is why sorting the collection in the viewmodel can be problematic. The `CollectionViewSource` approach is more code, but it automatically handles resorting on collection changes.

Answer (score -1):

or the non MVVM solution would have been....

I see your header is a StackPanel with 2 children and you whish to sort on the Content of the label, which is the 2nd child

You would access the label child as an array of position `[1]` since arrays are 0 based.

```
TreeView1.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
TreeView1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Header.Children[1].Content", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
TreeView1.Items.Refresh();
```